# Which has less of an impact on load times for accessing a variable in a JSP? A Page import or accessing an attribute from request / session scope?

Tags: java, jsp

I have a class which contains all of my constants. If I'm only referencing a single constant in my jsp, would it be quicker to import that class or to set the attribute via Action class and access it that way?

If the difference in speed / load time / memory is negligible, which method would be preferred?

I'm leaning towards the page import declaration, but I'd like to be sure.

Thanks

Edit: information on how that variable is being used: 'The constant is just a reference as a "maxRowLimit" used in some custom pagination'

Comment: It would be helpful to show a code fragment that shows how you are using this constant

Comment: The constant is just a reference as a "maxRowLimit" used in some custom pagination. 

I wasn't aware that its use could change which method of reference is preferred, my mistake that I didn't offer an example ahead of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Import is faster.** However be aware whenever you change the constant. The class with constants may no longer be present in the import list of the using class (the JSP generated servlet class), as such constants are filled in. And then the compiler will not automatically recompile the using class. For JSPs this means delete the cache of generated JSP classes.

It is faster as the imported constant is used **immediately**, actually substituted. In general it results in a byte code instruction of loading a constant. Object constants are stored in the classes constant pool and cannot be gotten any faster too.

Comment: Great thanks for the information. I'm familiar with the those kinds of restarts. 

Have you got any references / documentation to support imports being faster?

Comment: @JoopEggen  could you please elaborate? I am somewhat concerned that JSP would expect to be recompiled just because something it was referring to (i.e. something defined in another class) got assigned a new value.

Comment: I extended the answer. However this really is more of a micro-optimization. One might get more efficiency on net-related issues (caching, compression, minimizing, etcetera). Inspect load times.